# Issues with testing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am writing tests for my application. I have written quite a few tests and they were working fine. However, two of my tests keep failing and I am not sure why that is. The first test is a unsuccessful editing of a form. 
The test is given below

```
test "unsuccessfull editing of the scoreboard" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_scoreboard_path(@scoreboard)
    assert_template 'scoreboards/edit' (doesn't work)
    patch scoreboard_path(@scoreboard), scoreboard: { name_of_scoreboard: "a"* 51,
                                                      name_of_organization: "b"*60,
                                                      name_of_activity: "c"*60 }
    assert_template 'scoreboard/edit' (doesn't work)

  end
```

The error associated with this test is given below.

```
ScoreboardEditTest#test_unsuccessfull_editing_of_the_scoreboard [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/integration/scoreboard_edit_test.rb:13]:
expecting <"scoreboards/edit"> but rendering with <[]>
```

The controller for the following test is also given below.

```
def update
  @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:id])
  if @scoreboard.update_attributes(scoreboard_params)
    redirect_to @scoreboard
    flash[:success] = "Updated Successfully"
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
 end
```

After you get the edit_scoreboard_path, the edit scoreboard template should show up. I am not exactly sure why it gives me the error. I have the exact same thing with the user model and its working just fine. I think I am missing something in my understanding of it works.

The second test is a valid creation of a scoreboard. The test is given below.

```
test "valid creation of the scoreboard with passing validations" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get new_scoreboard_path
    assert_difference 'Scoreboard.count', 1 do
      post scoreboards_path, scoreboard: {name_of_scoreboard: "abc",
                                          name_of_organization: "def",
                                          name_of_activity: "ghi" }
      end
      assert_redirected_to scoreboard_path(@scoreboard) (doesn't work)
      assert_equal 'Scoreboard created successfully', flash[:success]
  end
```

It redirecting to the wrong scoreboard id. In the fixtures I have the id set as 1. The error message is given below.

```
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/scoreboards/1> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/scoreboards/941832920>.
```

I am not sure exactly what this means. As I mentioned, I have the ID set in the fixtures. I even manually set the id to '941832920'. It still gave me an error. Not sure why its doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 2nd test, I don't think you can set an id, it gets assigned by the database when the record is saved. A better way to check whether you get directed to the correct scoreboard path would be the preferred format: `assert_redirected_to scoreboard_path(assigns(:scoreboard))`.

Comment: The format above worked. I think I know why it worked but I am not completely sure. Also, Any clue why the first test is failing.

Comment: This is for anyone who has the same problem. The first test failed because of a before_action filter. I needed to be the correct user to be able to edit the scoreboard. The correct user is the user associated with the scoreboard. I created an association the my fixtures(.yml) file. Therefore, @user was the correct user and I was being redirected to the correct page